# Unable to load partial view on main view through Ajax in Razor Pages

Tags: ajax, asp.net-ajax, razor-pages

The Ajax Request is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            AddList();
        })

        function AddList(){
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Employees/Index?handler=OnGetPartial()",
                type: "GET",
                success: function (data) {
                    debugger
                    (".list").append(data);
                }
            });
        }
```

OnGetPartial() is the action method in the index model that returns the partial view. The .list class is the container where the partial view is to be rendered.
Index model code:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetPartial()
    {
        Employee = await _context.Employee.ToListAsync();
       return Partial("_ListPartialView", Employee);
    }
```

The partial view does not load at all instead the main view gets loaded in the main view.[image: Output of the code]

Comment: You cannot request partial pages directly. You can return a PartialViewResult from a named handler instead: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/ajax/partial-update

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working demo:

ajax:

```
function AddList(){
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Employees/Index?handler=Partial",
                type: "GET",
                success: function (data) {
                    debugger
                    $(".list").html(data);
                }
            });
        }
```

Pages/Shared/_ListPartialView.cshtml(Don't put `@page` into your partial view):

```
@model Employee
<h1>_ListPartialView</h1>
```

Comment: I haven't used @page in partial view, but the index page is still loaded into itself.

Comment: Is the route correct,or you can try to use devtools and check if you have errors in NetWork.

Comment: I have used dev tools the route seems correct because the  HTML gets rendered but not the partial view HTML it's rendering the main view page HTML.